# Can `l1` minimization be solved in Matlab using `fmincon`?

Tags: regression, matlab, lasso

Consider a MA system $$y[k] = x[k]+a_1*x[k-1] + a_2*x[k-2] + a_{9}*x[k-9] + n[k] \tag{1}$$ where $n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is Additive White Gaussian Noise and $x$ is a zero mean Gaussian white process of unity variance.

In this model only 3 coefficients are non-zero whereas the rest are all zero or close to zero. I should not assume the position of the sparse coefficients in order to apply sparse estimation methods. The correct approach is to assume that there are 10 coefficients out of which few are nonzero and majority are zero.

**QUESTION:** 
My approach is to split the objective function `J` into 2 parts--The first part being the OLS and the second part being the sparsification of the OLS estimate using a `l1` minimization approach?

Comment: A cool package you might want to checkout is [cvx](http://cvxr.com/).

Comment: @MatthewGunn: I want to understand what is actually going on inside the l1 minimization, so was thinking if there is a step by step approach

Comment: If this question's title wasn't Matlab-specific, and made more general to the issue of selecting nonzero coefficients in an MA model, it might be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a variable to transform a problem with an $L_1$ norm to a [linear programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Consider the $L_1$ minimization problem:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x_i$)} & \displaystyle \sum_i |x_i|\\
\mbox{subject to}  & ...
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
We can introduce variables $w_i$ and write it as a linear program:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x_i, w_i$)} & \displaystyle \sum_i w_i\\
 \mbox{subject to} & x_i \leq w_i \\
     & - x_i \leq w_i \\
    &...
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

If the other constraints are also linear, this can be solved with the `linprog` function in MATLAB.

#### Comment on your particular problem:

Since your problem also has quadratic terms in the objective, you would use `quadprog`. Using fmincon probably should work as well (though fmincon isn't specialized to your problem's structure). As I mentioned before, CVX is nice package as well. I'd check that your solution is the same using quadprog and CVX.

As I understand your problem:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $a_i$)} & \displaystyle \sum_t \left( y_t - \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}_t \right)^2 + \alpha \|\mathbf{a}\|_1\\
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

Which becomes:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $a_i, w_i$)} & \displaystyle \sum_t \left( y_t - \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}_t \right)^2 + \alpha \mathbf{1}' \mathbf{w}\\
\mbox{subject to}  & \mathbf{a} \preceq \mathbf{w} \\
& -\mathbf{a} \preceq \mathbf{w}
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

Rewriting more, the problem is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $a_i, w_i$)} & \displaystyle  \mathbf{a}'X'X\mathbf{a} - 2 \mathbf{y}' X \mathbf{a} + \alpha \mathbf{1}' \mathbf{w}\\
\mbox{subject to}  & \mathbf{a} \preceq \mathbf{w} \\
& -\mathbf{a} \preceq \mathbf{w}
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

Where $X = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1' \\ \mathbf{x}_2' \\ \ldots \end{bmatrix}$ etc...

Comment: @SrishtiM I think your confusion is that you don't solve $\min f(x) + g(x)$ by solving $\min f(x)$ and $\min g(x)$ separately. You don't obtain your `a` from maximum likelihood and then modify that result to take into account the $L_1$ norm. You need to formulate your problem as a single, optimization problem.

Comment: I see, this clear a lot of my misconception. Do you have some idea or suggestions as to how I should only code for the term $\sum_{i=1}^p |a_i|$? Or if possible how to code your answer using `quadprog` or constrained minimization?I don't understand how to make the matrices `A`,`Aeq` etc in the function signature and their meaning.

Comment: @SrishtiM You need to either (1) pull out the pencil and paper and figure out what those matrices `A`, `Aeq` etc... are or (2) use a package like CVX which makes it somewhat more intuitive to write down your optimization problem.